# Larger worlds in Minecraft Pi

Tags: minecraft

I have Minecraft Pi installed on my Raspberry Pi. I have built something, but it is touching the edge of the world. I would like to know if it is possible, and how to increase the world size in Minecraft Pi. If not, is it possible to rearrange the chunks?

Comment: This would probably be best asked on Gaming.SE, or Stack Overflow if you want to do it programmatically.

Comment: Isn't the Minecraft Pi that is included with the Raspbian distribution a limited (alpha version) - I'd doubt that Gaming.SE would give this (probably) *Raspberry Pi specific* version much consideration!